# Do I have to use an interface to define the elements of an object with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can do this:

```
var a: number = 99;
```

but how can I define `a` when it's inside an object:

```
var ob = { a: 99 }
```

or

```
class AClass {

    ob = { a: 99 };

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

Is the only way to do this with an interface?

Comment: Sorry, Are you asking if you can define the object ob's property as a or set the value of property a which is in ob.

Comment: I want to define the a inside of ob as a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface is not required. If you just want to define the "shape" of your object, without an explicit class/interface declaration, you can do so like this:

`var ob: { a:number } = {a: 99};`

In your class example, it would look like this:

```
class AClass {

    ob: { a:number } = { a: 99 };

    constructor() {
      // tsc knows that this.ob.a is of type number
    }

}
```

This works with complex objects as well:

```
    var ob: {
        a:number;
        b: {
            stringVal:string;
            numero:number;
            bitflag:Boolean
        }
    } = {
        a: 99,
        b: {
            stringVal: "Some string value here",
            numero:1234,
            bitflag:true
        }
    };
```

This syntax can be useful in function declaration where you know you're expecting an object with specific properties:

```
function(someObject: {stringVal:string; numero:number})
    // TypeScript now knows that someObject will have a "stringVal" string property, and a "numero" number property
}
```

Now, having said that, I'd encourage you to think carefully about whether or not an interface is better suited. If this is a simple object shape, and a one-off situation that's not going to recur, declaring the shape inline (as described above) may be fine, but if you are *ever* going to have an object with the same shape elsewhere, it probably makes sense to declare it as an interface, then you can re-use the interface. And this is doubly-true if you are working with a complex object that goes many levels deep. It could get pretty ugly trying to do it all inline.

Comment: Josh - Thanks for your advice. Can you tell me, is it also possible to do define the shape of a property in a class or must I create an interface for the whole class ?

Comment: Yup, it appears so. I just tried it in TypeScript and then updated my answer with an example. If I've answered your question please mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this syntax is called an "object type literal." Currently described in [section 3.7 of the TypeScript spec](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf#page=42).

Comment: Sorry if my question is confusing. I just edited the question to show what I mean. Your answer about the variables works fine but I have a problem with class properties. Is there a way to define these or do I need to do the whole class. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use that "object type literal" syntax anywhere, including to define the type of a property on a class. Are you getting an error when you try to do this? I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class like this:

```
var a: number = 99;

class Ob{
    constructor(public a: number){}
}

var newOb = new Ob(a);
newOb.a // should equal 99 then.
```

Comment: Is the other alternative to define an interface? Given a very simple object with perhaps 10 properties and no functionality what would you do?

Comment: I tend to always define classes for making data sort of objects. A typescript interface is only a design time feature so I don't find it helps much with creating data objects, I use them primarily for defining controllers, services, repositories, etc.